# MySQL, stored procedure (stored function) and argument as rows from query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, arguments

Is it possible send to stored procedure arguments as rows from query?
I mean you have stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE XYZ (IN ARGUMENTS)
BEGIN
*/ how to get values from ARGUMENTS? /*
END;
```

and you send data to procedure in CALL directive like:

```
CALL XYZ(SELECT COL1,COL2 FROM TABLE WHERE CONDITION is true)
```

Or you have only to send CONDITION as a argument for procedure and invoke "SELECT" inside the store procedure?:(

Regards,
Artik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's impossible in Mysql. You can only use [Mysql Data Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-overview.html) as arguments of precedure, i.e. Mysql stored procedure/function can't use tables as arguments - only single-type values.